# Question about adding Google map into rails's page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to making a very easy sample example Rails by following this website https://melvinchng.github.io/rails/GoogleMap.html#62-configure-gmaps4rails, and I thought evething was smooth, the command were ok when I ran them.

The problem is, when I ran the host, the map can not load as I expect. I do not know where is the problem. The cmd just said to me that

```
app/views/routers/index.html.erb:41
  Rendered routers/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 3.2ms | Allocations: 931)
[Webpacker] Compiling…
[Webpacker] Compilation failed:
```

Here is my page, I can not add the map
https://ibb.co/LSj1RfM

Could you please give me some ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have any other lines after the `[Webpacker] Compilation failed:` one?

Comment: @ZedTuX after the `[Webpacker] Compilation failed:` , I have just this line

 `Completed 200 OK in 3406ms (Views: 3403.7ms ActiveRecord: 0.3ms Allocations: 7711)`

So, I think this line is not important

Comment: What are the results of `rake assets:precompile`?

Comment: the results of `rake assets:precompile` is `C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/fileutils-1.2.0/lib/fileutils.rb:1663: warning: previous definition of METHODS was here
I, [2019-11-13T08:07:01.593179 #1068]  INFO -- : Writing C:/Users/NTQ/Desktop/x/public/assets/manifest-cadda289ef9c70eaa0879a36e6263cb33f7523a16b3ef862e0b8609cdc2bdab1.js

Compiling…
Compilation failed:
`

Comment: Is your repository a public one?